# ¿Cómo compilar código de C en R?

Tags: c, r, compilar

Estoy intentando modificar una librería de R que funciona ejecutando algunos de sus loops en C y en Fortran, así que estoy intentando compilar código de C en R para probar mis cambios. Nunca he trabajado con C antes, así que he seguido los pasos descritos en esta web http://mcglinn.web.unc.edu/blog/linking-c-with-r-in-windows/

He descargado Rtools, lo he añadido a las variables de entorno y he creado un fichero con unas funciones en C. Pero al intentar compilarlo, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
C:\Users\alvaromc317\ZZ_ALVARO>R CMD SHLIB sequence_examples.c
make: *** No rule to make target `sequence_examples.o', needed by `sequence_examples.dll'.  Stop.
Warning message:
comando ejecutado 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="sequence_examples.dll" OBJECTS="sequence_examples.o"' tiene estatus 2
```

Llevo 2 días con esto sin resultados así que agradeceré cualquier consejo.

Gracias a los comentarios he podido resolver el problema anterior (era un problema con el PATH) sin embargo ahora tengo otro problema. Se ha compilado el código y generado un archivo dll, pero cuando intento usar dyn.load en R para cargar el código compilado me da el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/alvaromc317/ZZ_ALVARO/sequence_examples.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
ficado.
```

Añadir que mi ordenador funciona con una arquitectura x64, y R, Rstudio y Rtools han sido instaladas para la arquitectura x64

Un saludo,
Álvaro

Comment: Me da la impresión que te falta algún path por definir y el compilador falla al generar el código objeto (`sequence_examples.o`). Al faltar ese fichero falla después al intentar generar la DLL

Comment: Rtools básicamente son todas las herramientas de compilación de código C y C++ conocidas como mingw. Revisa como te comenta eferion el tema de los paths, puedes probar ir a la carpeta dónde tienes el código C y compilar el módulo manualmente a ver si funciona: `gcc sequence_examples.c` si funciona te debería generar un archivo objeto `*.o` sino lo probable que sea un problema de path. Revisa también por las dudas la versión instalada de Rtools, es decir si es compatible con la arquitectura de tu equipo (32 o 64 bits)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, he podido resolver el primer problema pero sigo sin conseguir que el código de C me funcione, he editado la pregunta con la nueva información

Comment: Después de intalar Rtools, la siguiente prueba la funciona en R `library(Rcpp); evalCpp("2 + 2")`, o genera algún error.